# Can A-GPS work without a GPS Receiver?

Tags: gps

Any body please tell me if a Assited-GPS can function without a GPS receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's impossible: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS

A-GPS uses other data to improve the quality of GPS.